# checking for multiple values in a single column in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

So I'm not sure whether I asked the question well. I'm new to laravel and right now I'm building an application where I need to fetch data for a user if certain conditions are met. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

Select from database where userid = $user and userstatus = active or inactive. or pending. 
So all rows with the user id($user) and status(active, inactive and pending) will be returned. 
I tried doing:

```
  $users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('status', '=', 'active')
    ->orwhere('status', '=', 'inactive')
    ->orwhere('status', '=', 'pending')
    ->get();
```

This returned all the data in that particular table. What is the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at least two options for how to do this you can use, including both so you have one for use in this case and one for general usage. Using a function in where creates a new block, so works like adding parentheses to your query

```
$users = DB::table('users')
  ->where('id', $user)
  ->where(function($query) {
  $query->where('status', 'active')
    ->orWhere('status', 'inactive')
    ->orWhere('status', 'pending');
})->get();
```

or

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->whereIn('status', ['active', 'inactive', 'pending'])->get();
```

Comment: Use the second approach @veightar

Comment: Yea. It worked. The second is shorter and better. Thanks

Comment: The second example is working properly but there are missing some characters: "DB::table" missing ":"  and "...'pending'] " missing final square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('userid', $userid)
    ->whereIn('status',['active', 'inactive','pending'])
    ->get();
```